# Why spawn scp does not work correctly?

Tags: linux, shell, redhat, scp

Below is my script containing spawn scp related script.

```
spawn scp -r /usr/local/clo/Jenkins.zip root@xu.domain.com:/usr/local/clo
expect "password:"
send "111111\r"
expect "*\r"
expect "\r"
```

But when I execute it, it output the following log and it can not transfer the file correctly.
**

```
spawn scp -r /usr/local/clo/Jenkins.zip root@xu.domain.com:/usr/local/clo
root@xu.domain.com's password:
Jenkins.zip                                                                                                                  0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
```

**

I was wondering how does the '0%' happen? If I manually execute the **scp** script from console, it can send the file completely.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this happens because the output of the spawned process includes \r (carriage return) characters when displaying the progress meter, try to add `expect eof` at the end of your Expect script.

But to deal with timeout problems, it should be better to detect the progress meter, using `exp_continue` to continue executing while the progress meter is displayed:

```
spawn scp -r /usr/local/clo/Jenkins.zip root@xu.domain.com:/usr/local/clo
expect "password:"
send "111111\r"
expect {
    "ETA" {exp_continue}
    "100%" {}
}
expect eof
```

You could also add `exp_internal 1` at the beginning of the script (it reports internal activity of the expect command).

Comment: thanks. It seems to work. but when it came to 84%, time out occur.

Comment: You are right, for a large file you could increase the timeout (or disable it using `set timeout -1`), but it should be better to detect the progress meter (I have updated my previous post).